# Count documents with same array field

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many

I'm new in mongo and I don't really know how to bite this:

Let's say we have this schema in `owners` collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: "name",
    cars: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ObjectId, ...]
}
```

Where _ids in `cars` array relate to other collection, say `cars`.
Now, every owner can have many cars, and every car can have more than one owner (just many-to-many relationship).

E.g.

```
[
{'_id':'1', 'name':'Mr. A', cars: ['1','2',3',4',5'] },
{'_id':'2', 'name':'Mr. B', cars: ['6'] },
{'_id':'3', 'name':'Mr. C', cars: ['1','2'] },
{'_id':'4', 'name':'Mr. D', cars: ['2',3',5','6','7'] },
{'_id':'5', 'name':'Mr. E', cars: ['6'] }
]
```

The problem is how to check which owners Mr. A share cars with.
How to get result like this for Mr. A:

```
[
{'owner_id': '3', 'cars': 2},
{'owner_id': '4', 'cars': 3}
]
```

I tried to use aggregation framework, but I can't see the way to do it.

---

**EDIT**
I wrote this function, but i don't know if it's the right way

```js
function (owner)
{
    ret = {}
    owner.cars.forEach(function (car) {
        db.owners.find({cars: car}).forEach(function(own2){
            if(own2._id == owner._id){
                return;
            }
            if(ret[own2._id.str] !== undefined){
                ret[own2._id.str] += 1;
            }
            else{
                ret[own2._id.str] = 1;
            }
        });
    });
    return ret
}
```

Comment: you can't do this in one query/one aggregation.  You can do it with one map/reduce job but two queries will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned only with owners that share with Mr. A, you can try the following:

First, get the cars owned by Mr. A:

```
var cars = db.owners.findOne({'name':'Mr. A'})
```

Then perform aggregation on owner with cars similar with Mr. A excluding Mr. A.

```
db.owners.aggregate(
  {'$match':{$and : [{'cars':{'$in':cars}},{'name':{'$ne':'Mr. A'}}]}},
  {'$unwind':'$cars'},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$_id','owner_id':'$_id','cars':{$sum:1}}}
)
```

I have not tested the above queries but I encourage you to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with 2 queries. It will require you to store a temporary variable (which I've named 'cars') in your calling code. It should look something like this:

```
var cars = db.owners.findOne({'name':'Mr. A'}, {cars:1})

var shared = db.owners.find({'name':{ '$ne': 'Mr. A'}, 'cars': {'$in':cars}}, {'name':1})
```